# Can I use pydap.client in windows?

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I tried to use pydap.client to access netcdf data from thredds server on a windows PC. I installed pydap using conda `conda install -c conda-forge pydap=3.2.0`.

When I run the code

```
from pydap.client import open_url
```

I get the following error message

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'gunicorn' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I tried to install gunicorn, However, gunicorn is not available for Windows.

Can't I use pydap.client in Windows?